# Several String Manipulation in R

Tags: r, string

I have these 5 problems with strings in R:

**1)** Numbers between the third and fourth dot. Disregard the “0” to the left if any.

ex: I have: 01.030.131.0**12962**.000000 -1/1 -
I need: *12962*

**2)** Numbers between the last and penultimate point.

ex: I have: 33.31.**17811849**.0
I need: *17811849*

**3)** Number between the second and third "/". Disregard the “0” to the left if any.

ex: I have: 2001/96/000000**36**/0
I need: *36*

**4)** Number after the second dot. Disregard “0”,"." or "-" to the left if any.

ex: I have: 0118.11.**54.779-9**
I need: *547799*

**5)** 7 numbers after numbers 775, 776 or 746.

ex: I have: 030692018990775**0240991000**
I need: *0240991*

Comment: Most regex questions are resolved by reading through https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 and working through each problem. Other good references include https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/.

Comment: First one: \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.[0]([1-9]?\d*)\.\d+

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```r
gsub("^0", "", strsplit("01.030.131.012962.000000", "[.]")[[1]][4])
# [1] "12962"

gsub("^0", "", tail(strsplit("33.31.17811849.0", "[.]")[[1]], 2)[1])
# [1] "17811849"

gsub("^0+", "", strsplit("2001/96/00000036/0", "/")[[1]][3])
# [1] "36"

strsplit("0118.11.54.779-9", "[-.]")[[1]][3] ## your question is inconsistent here ...
# [1] "54"
strsplit("0118.11.54.779-9", "[-.]")[[1]][-(1:2)]
# [1] "54"  "779" "9"  
strsplit("0118.11.54.779-9", "[-.]")[[1]][3:4]
# [1] "54"  "779"
paste(strsplit("0118.11.54.779-9", "[-.]")[[1]][3:4], collapse = "")
# [1] "54779"

regmatches("0306920189907750240991000", gregexpr("(?<=(775|776|746)).*", "0306920189907750240991000", perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "0240991000"
```